# Run protractor e2e tests from Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: protractor, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm having trouble trying to run Protractor e2e tests from VSTS within a release definition.

Steps I have in my release definition are:

1. **Azure File Copy:** This copies the source code from a Git repo to an Azure VM that will run the tests
2. **PowerShell on Target Machines:** This executes a Powershell script on the Azure VM.

The powershell script is below:

```
cd c:/App
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
npm install
npm run e2e
```

From VSTS, it fails and displays the following error:

```
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2854207Z     Deployment started on target machine...
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2854587Z 
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2855184Z System.AggregateException: Failed to execute the powershell script. Consult the logs below for details of the error.
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2855708Z 
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2856210Z System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2856743Z  +At C:\scripts\Rune2eTests.ps1:3 char:1
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2857225Z + npm install
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2857694Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2858464Z  CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2859049Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :NativeCommandError
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2859393Z 
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2860037Z Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2860677Z  +At C:\scripts\Rune2eTests.ps1:4 char:1
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2861172Z + npm run e2e
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2861603Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2862153Z  CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (Without `from` ...t this warning.:String) [], RemoteException
2018-01-24T05:27:47.2862721Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :NativeCommandError
```

It does run all the Protractor tests successfully when I remote into the Azure VM and just run the powershell script, but it doesn't when VSTS runs it. Another issue is that it doesn't output in the console what tests passed/failed in VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with PowerShell task instead:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "[password]" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("[username]", $password)
$sc = {
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
E:
cd E:\dd\angularclitest
npm run test
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName [machine] -ScriptBlock $sc -credential $cred
```

Note: Username and password can be stored in the build/release variables.